# ASP.NET Core Model Data Annotations Custom ErrorMessage doesn't show up

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I created a static class named ValidationMessages that has some string error messages and this is the code:

```
public static class ValidationMessages
    {
        public const string Required = "مقدار این فیلد اجباریست.";
        public const string MaxLength = "مقدار این فیلد بیش از حد مجاز است.";
        public const string TitleShouldBeUnique = "امکان ثبت عنوان تکراری وجود ندارد.";
        public const string InformationNotFound = "اطلاعات درخواست شده یافت نشد.";
    }
```

In my model I used annotation like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.Required)]
[MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxLength)]
public string Title { get; private set; }
```

The problem is I get default error messages like `The Title field is required.`.

I also tried to use a string like `ErrorMessage = "تست"` but it didn't work and I get the default error messages again.

All of my html inputs are similar to this one:

```
<form method="post">        
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.CreateProductCategory.Title" class="form-label">عنوان</label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.CreateProductCategory.Title" class="form-control" >
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.CreateProductCategory.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use `[StringLength]` not `[MaxLength]` - the `MaxLength` attribute is for EF, while `StringLength` is for model-binding.

Comment: It didn't work out. but ty

Comment: add Unobtrusive JQuery Validation Scripts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation

Comment: I try your code and the page show the error message from `ValidationMessages` class correctly, Have you add js validation successfully?